# Induction cooker power receiver

Tags: power-engineering, induction

While building some small (single digit wattage) inductive power transmission systems, I wondered if a larger one could be build using an induction cooker as transmitter.

What would be the mandatory properties of an inductive receiver to please an usual household inductive cooking plate and make it engage in power transmission? Would the coil and capacitor of an equal plate make a good resonant receiver?

Comment: Induction heater cooker coils are probably designed to operate from a DC supply as high as the rectified AC mains and this will usually mean they have many,many turns so, if you are looking for a few watts, it's far more effective to have a few turns and run from (say) 12 volts DC.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to defeat the "safety interlock" circuitry: induction cookers turn themselves off when no iron object is detected.  On a small portable desktop cooker, I found that a 3" piece of #24ga sheet steel was enough to keep the unit turned on.  Of course the steel would grow quite hot!   IIR the output frequency was 65KHz with no large cookpot present.

For lots of DIY projects, search: [induction cooker "tesla coil"](https://www.google.com/search?q=induction%20cooker%20%22tesla%20coil%22)

Online, you should be able to find a used desktop cooker for under $30.  Replacement [drive-coils on eBay seem to be around $20.](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=coil%20cooker%20induction%20-zvs&_sop=15)  I also see lots of replacement capacitors 0.33uF, also 3uF and 4.7uF (probably the 0.33uF is for the coil resonator, with the larger values for AC filters/chokes.)

.

Simplified partial schematic from [Hacking IKEA 2KW induction cooker...](http://kaizerpowerelectronics.dk/general-electronics/hacking-ikea-2kw-induction-hob/)

[image]
.

[image]